# What Species of Trees are These?

Tags: trees

I live in Central Ohio and I have this grouping of trees in my back yard but I don’t know why they are. Does anyone know what type of trees these are?

[image][image][image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're common hackberries - Celtis occidentalis (the bark and leaf shape are the keys). The leaves are a pale yellow/chartreuse in the fall, and the tree produces small bark blue/black berries that birds mostly eat.

Wikipedia has a nice page on the tree: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celtis_occidentalis